# WCF exception AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint

At the client side when consuming the service am getting the following exception:
The message with To 'net.tcp://puv15xgts:55201/Ois//Patient/PatientHistory/PatientHistoryService.svc' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

Here is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ospUri" value="http://PUV15XGTS:55000/OSPServices/ServerSettings.svc"/>
    <add key="IAuthorization" value="http://PUV15XGTS:55000/OSPServices/Authorization.svc"/>
    <add key="ospSystem" value="OSP8"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="secureOptions" type="VMS.SDF.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, VMS.SDF"/>
        <add name="faultTransport" type="VMS.SDF.FaultTransfer.FaultTransferExtensionElement, VMS.SDF"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" portSharingEnabled="true" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="67108864" maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxNameTableCharCount="67108864"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536000"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecuredService">
          <secureOptions validateRequest="true" securityLevel="Core" tokenTimeToLive="60"/>
          <faultTransport/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="VMS.WebServices.Ois.Patient.PatientHistoryService.ServiceImplementation.PatientHistoryService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />-->
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:55201/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VMS.WebServices.Ois.Patient.PatientHistoryService.ServiceContracts.IPatientHistoryService" behaviorConfiguration="SecuredService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="VMS.WebServices.Ois.Patient.PatientHistoryService.ServiceContracts.IPatientHistoryService" behaviorConfiguration="SecuredService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please help whats going wrong here.

Comment: **" Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree."** Did you check them?

Comment: Where i can check it? bit new to WCF

Comment: Check the address in the service config and check the address in the client config (if you're using configs, or check the address in the code if you're doing it in code).